# Repeated index is not storing in associated array in Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

I am trying to store the array with the index and its value in associated array, But it is not storing repeated index with different value. When I alert this json value only unique value is displaying .Here is my code :

```
 arr[1]="AAA";
 arr[2]="BBB"
 arr[3]="CCC"
 arr[2]="DDD"
 arr[2]="HHH" 

var jsonString = JSON.stringify(arr);
 alert(jsonString);
```

Comment: `arr[2]` can only hold one value, so the ultimate `arr[2]="HHH"` is the only one that will remain

Comment: A given index in an array can only have one value.

Comment: @MattBall In PHP the same thing would happen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JavaScript does not allow repeated keys. When you write a value in a key that is already set, you are overwriting it and not creating a new key.

You may store multiple values in a key by using an inner list, like this:

```
arr[1]="AAA";
arr[2]=["BBB"];
arr[3]="CCC";
arr[2].push("DDD");
arr[2].push("HHH");

var jsonString = JSON.stringify(arr);
alert(jsonString);
```

If you want all your keys to behave like that, you can create a function to replicate this behavior:

```
function pushToKey(arr, key, value) {
    var innerArr = arr[key];
    if (innerArr) {
        innerArr.push(value);
    } else {
        arr[key] = [value];
    };
}
```

Then always use this function:

```
var myArr = [];
pushToKey(myArr, 1, "AAA");
pushToKey(myArr, 2, "BBB");
pushToKey(myArr, 3, "CCC");
pushToKey(myArr, 2, "DDD");
pushToKey(myArr, 2, "HHH");
```

This will make all values inside `myArr` to be stored as an array.

Comment: In my case I have to pass  the dynamic  repeated data as a index along with its value.Is any other solution is there for that.?

Comment: I've edited the answer, check if it is what you are looking for.

Comment: I have used pushToKey function and did it.

Answer (score 2):

First, javascript has no concept of an associatively indexed array.  You have either numerically indexed arrays or objects.

Second, if you try to write data to a given index (or property on an object) that is already defined, you WILL overwrite that value.  This is common in any programming language.

It sounds like you simply need to rethink your data structure.

Comment: @user3829086 I'm guessing people downvoted because arrays are a fairly basic programming feature, and SO ["is a question and answer site for professional and enthusiast programmers"](http://stackoverflow.com/tour), so many users would expect questioners to know this